# C# positioning buttons

Tags: c#, winforms, button, position

I have 3 buttons in my form. What I need to do is when I make the actual form bigger or smaller, the buttons should change their position and size so they look good, so they wouldn't remain the same size and position. I tried to use the anchors, but that does not work very well. What can I use to solve my problem?

Comment: @Nalaka526 probably stupid question, but what's WCF? And if I understood correctly- i'm using Windows Forms Applications.

Comment: Sorry, not WCF its WPF (edited already) :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check dock and anchor properties

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=afsx1IJULLI

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should set both left and right, or top and bottom anchors to resize control. If you'll set only one anchor from these pairs, then control will be positioned instead of resizing.

Docking will resize control, because it is equivalent of setting three or more anchors.

Comment: I think I didn't really explain what I'm trying to achieve. I don't want to fill the entire form with the buttons (if i'll use the anchors it will do that). I want them to just be a little bit bigger or smaller (depends on how big the actual form is). Hopefully I made my problem a bit clearer.

Comment: @user3137498 so, you want to have several discrete sizes of buttons which will be applied according to form size?

Comment: @MarisP there is no built in functionality for what you want, and actually I have never seen discrete controls resizing on winforms (well, except integral height setting for listbox). I think if you will provide several screenshots of what you trying to achieve then your intent would be more clear, and some custom solution will be found

Answer (score 0):

Try using TableLayoutPanel, put your buttons inside the columns of the table

Answer (score 0):

`Look good` is different all the time. I like placing buttons in [StackPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stackpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and setting [AutoSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.autosize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to true. This fixes two issues:

1. If user has 150% font in Windows settings - your UI does not break;
2. if you resize window to be very small - your buttons do not enforce minimal width/height and adapt to ratio user has chosen